# Выборка за месяц hibernate

Tags: java, дата, hibernate

На входе дата в виде Timespamp"2015-09-01 00:00:00.0" с первым числом месяца, как получить записи начиная с даты которая имеется, до конца месяца?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String test = String.valueOf(timestamp);
test = test.substring(0,7);
test = test + "-%";
Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductEntity where date like :datq");
query.setString("datq",test);
resultList = query.list();
```